# What does `UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize()`actually do？

Tags: ios, c, swift, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

The following is base on my guess. Someone please point out the parts that I understand incorrectly.

If I have a class, of which an instance occupies 128 bits, called `Class128Bits`. And my program runs on a 64 bits computer.

First, I call `let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Calss128Bits>.allocate(capacity: 2)`
the memory layout should look like this:

```
000-063 064 bits chaos
064-127 064 bits chaos
128-255 128 bits chaos
256-383 128 bits chaos
```

If I call `pointer.pointee = aClass128Bits`, it crashes because the pointers in the first two grids have not been initialized yet. Accessing to what they point to leads to unpredictable results.

But if I call `pointer.initialize(to: aClass128Bits, count: 2)`, the pointers could be initialized like this:

```
000-063 address to offset 128
064-127 address to offset 256
128-255 a copy of aClass128Bits
256-383 a copy of aClass128Bits
```

Then any accesses will be safe. 
However this cannot explain why `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>` does not crash.

---

### Original

The case I am facing:
[image: Crash]

The pointer to `Int` works fine, but the one to `String` crashes.
I know that I need to initialize it like this:
[image: Not Crash]

But I can't see the reason why I need to pass `"42"` twice.
In C, I might do something similar like this:

```
char *pointer = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
memcpy(pointer, "42", 3);
free(pointer)
```

If `allocate` equals `malloc`, `free` equals `deallocate`, `memcpy` equals `pointee{ set }`,
then what do `initialize` and `deinitialize` actually do?
And why does my code crash?

Comment: Have a look at the descriptions of these methods at [Swiftdoc](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/UnsafeMutablePointer/). Specifically w.r.t. acessing the `pointee` property, the precondition reads _"Precondition: the pointee has been initialized with an instance of type `Pointee`."_. For additional details, refer to the associated [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/UnsafePointer.swift.gyb).

Comment: Your _guess_ has a big flaw. In Swift, class is reference type and the content of an instance will not be copied without calling any sort of copying methods. `UnsafeMutablePointer<Class128Bits>.allocate(capacity: 2)` just allocates 16-byte region, 2 pointers in 64-bit platform. `let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Class128Bits>.allocate(capacity: 2);print(malloc_size(pointer))` -> `16`.

Comment: "func initialize(to: Pointee, count: Int)
Initializes self.pointee with count consecutive copies of newValue" So what does Apple mean in its documentation by saying COPIES?

Comment: It does not say "copy the content". When `newValue` is a reference, the reference is copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason you need `initialize()`, and the only one as for now maybe, is

**for ARC**.

You'd better think with local scope variables, when seeing how ARC works:

```
func test() {
    var refVar: RefType = initValue  //<-(1)
    //...
    refVar = newValue //<-(2)
    //...
    //<-(3) just before exiting the loacl scope
}
```

For a usual assignment as (2), Swift generates some code like this:

```
swift_retain(_newValue)
swift_release(_refVar)
_refVar = _newValue
```

(Assume `_refVar` and `_newValue` are unmanaged pseudo vars.)

`Retain` means incrementing the reference count by 1, and `release` means decrementing the reference count by 1.

---

But, think what happens when the initial value assignment as at (1).

If the usual assignment code was generated, the code might crash at this line:

```
swift_release(_refVar)
```

because newly allocated region for a var may be filled with garbages, so `swift_release(_refVar)` cannot be safely executed.

Filling the newly region with zero (null) and `release` safely ignoring the null could be one solution, but it's sort of redundant and not effective.

So, Swift generates this sort of code for initial value assignment:

(for already retained values, if you know ownership model, owned by you.)

```
_refVar = _initValue
```

(for unretained values, meaning you have no ownership yet.)

```
swift_retain(_initValue)
_refVar = _initValue
```

This is **`initialize`**.

No-releasing the garbage data, and assign an initial value, retaining it if needed.

(The above explanation of "usual assignment" is a little bit simplified, Swift omits `swift_retain(_newValue)` when not needed.)

---

When exiting the local scope at (3), Swift just generates this sort of code:

```
swift_release(_refVar)
```

So, this is **`deinitialize`**.

---

Of course, you know retaining and releasing are not needed for primitive types like `Int`, so `initialize` and `deinitialize` may be `donothing` for such types.

And when you define a value type which includes some reference type properties, Swift generates `initialize` and `deinitialize` procedures specialized for the type.

---

The local scope example works for the regions allocated on the stack, and `initialize()` and `deinitialize()` of `UnsafeMutablePointer` works for the regions allocated in the heap.

And Swift is evolving so swift, that you might find another reason for needing `initialize()` and `deinitialize()` in the future, you'd better make it a habit to `initialize()` and `deinitialize()` all allocated `UnsafeMutablePointer`s of any `Pointee` types.

Comment: So to `.initialize()` is just for feeding in something that can be `swift_release()` when the first assignment happens? It is possible, but a little hard to believe.

Comment: I don't agree ... please, see my answer. Swift's Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer<T> is maintained by ARC, not the .pointee.

Answer (score 4):

```
let pointer0 = UnsafeMutablePointer<String>.allocate(capacity: 1)
let pointer1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)
```

let check the size of both

```
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: pointer0) // 8
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: pointer1) // 8
```

let check the value of .pointee

```
pointer0.pointee // CRASH!!!
```

while

```
pointer1.pointee // some random value
```

Why? The answer is as simple, as it can be. We allocated 8 bytes, independently from "associated" Type. Now is clear, that 8 bytes in memory are not enough to store any String. the underlying memory must be referenced indirectly. But there are some 8 random bytes there ... Loading what is in the memory with address represented by 8 random bytes as a String will most likely crash :-)

Why didn't it crash in the second case? Int value is 8 bytes long and the address can be represented as Int value.

let's try in the Playground

```
import Foundation

let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CFString>.allocate(capacity: 1)    

let us = Unmanaged<CFString>.passRetained("hello" as CFString)

pointer.initialize(to: us.takeRetainedValue())
print(pointer.pointee)

us.release()

// if this playground crash, try to run it again and again ... -)
print(pointer.pointee)
```

look what it prints to me :-)

```
hello
(
    "<__NSCFOutputStream: 0x7fb0bdebd120>"
)
```

There is no miracle behind. pointer.pointee is trying to represent what is in the memory, which address is stored in our pointer, as a value of its associated type. It never crashes for Int because every 8 continues bytes somewhere in the memory can be represented as Int.

Swift use ARC, but creating the Unsafe[Mutable]Poiner doesn't allocate any memory for the instance of T, destroying it doesn't deallocate any memory for it.

Typed memory **must be initialized before use and deinitialized after use**. This is done using initialize and deinitialize methods respectively. Deinitialization is only required for non-trivial types. That said, including deinitialization is a good way to future-proof your code in case you change to something non-trivial

**Why doesn't assignment to .pointee with Int value crash?**

1. Initialize store the address of value
2. Assignment to pointee update the value at stored address

Without initializing It most likely will crash, only the probability is less by modifying only 8 bytes in memory at some random address.

trying this

```
import Darwin
var k = Int16.max.toIntMax()
typealias MyTupple = (Int32,Int32,Int8, Int16, Int16)

var arr: [MyTupple] = []
repeat {
    let p = UnsafeMutablePointer<MyTupple>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    if k == 1 {
        print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: p), MemoryLayout.alignment(ofValue: p),MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: p))
    }
    arr.append(p.pointee)
    k -= 1
    defer {
        p.deallocate(capacity: 1)
    }
} while k > 0

let s = arr.reduce([:]) { (r, v) -> [String:Int] in
    var r = r
    let c = r["\(v.0),\(v.1),\(v.2),\(v.3)"] ?? 0
    r["\(v.0),\(v.1),\(v.2),\(v.3)"] = c + 1
    return r
}
print(s)
```

I received

```
8 8 8
["0,0,-95,4104": 6472, "0,0,0,0": 26295]
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

It doesn't look very random, is it? That explains, why the crash with the typed pointer to Int is very unlikely.

Comment: This answer is not showing any facts inconsistent with my answer. Your `pointer0.pointee` crashes because you have not `initialize`d the pointed region. `pointer1.pointee` does not crash because `Int` does not have any member that needs to be managed by ARC.

Comment: So, as long as I assign to an uninitialized UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> for enough times, it will still crash?

Comment: Not necessary, but it could happen

Comment: @CopperCash it is hard to answer because there is no guarantee, what will happen. I can imagine, that most likely nothing wrong will happen, but as it is mentioned in apple docs, typed memory must be initialized before use and deinitialized after use, and do it always before using .pointee is a really good idea. Think about .pointee as a view to the memory which address is stored in Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer. In reality, the value is not necessary to be somewhere in addressable memory, it could be in processor register ... etc.

Comment: I will definitely initialize every Unsafe<Mutable>Pointer in any serious development. What I tried to make sure was whether the fact the my UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> didn't crash was just a coincident.

Comment: @user3441734 This works:

let instance: SampleClass = SampleClass()
unowned let weakInstance: SampleClass = instance
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<SampleClass>.allocate(capacity: 1)
pointer.initialize(to: weakInstance)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
  print(weakInstance)
  print(pointer.pointee)
  pointer.deinitialize(count: 1)
  pointer.deallocate()
}

This crashes:
let instance: SampleClass = SampleClass()
unowned let weakInstance: SampleClass = instance
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
  print(weakInstance)
}

Comment: Here's some elaboration on that UnsafeMutablePointer does participate in ARC: https://academy.realm.io/posts/russ-bishop-unsafe-swift/

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation it is possible to conclude that `.initialize()` is a method that :

> Initializes memory starting at self with the elements of source.

And `.deinitialize()` is a method that :

> De-initializes the count Pointees starting at self, returning their
> memory to an uninitialized state.

We should understand that when we are using `UnsafeMutablePointer` we should manage memory on our own. And methods that are described above help us to do this.

So in your case lets analyze example that you provide:

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<String>.allocate(capacity: 1)
// allocate a memory space

pointer.initialize(to: "42")
// initialise memory

pointer.pointee // "42"
// reveals what is in the pointee location

pointer.pointee = "43"
// change the contents of the memory

pointer.deinitialize()
// return pointer to an unintialized state

pointer.deallocate(1)
// deallocate memory
```

So your code crashes because you do not initialize memory and try to set value.

Previously in objective-c when we are working with objects we always use `[[MyClass alloc] init]]`.

In this case :

alloc:

> allocates a part of memory to hold the object, and returns the
> pointer.

init:

> sets up the initial parameters of the object and returns it.

So basically `.initialize()` sets the value to the allocated memory part. When you create an object only with `alloc` you only set reference to empty memory part in the heap. When you call `.initialize()` you set value to this memory allocation in the heap.

Nice [article](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/objective-c-pointers-and-swift/) about the pointers.

Comment: Could you please explain further about what will happen IN MEMORY after `initialize` being called? In C, I don't need to initialize anything after I `alloc` the memory.

Comment: After `allocate`, I should have some allocated MEMORY and a POINTER references it. I understand that it will crash if I try to read the content in these uninitialized MEMORY via the POINTER. But `pointee{ set }` does not read the content, it writes. Writing the MEMORY is supposed to be similar with the behavior of `memcpy`, and not supposed to crash the program.